# how to upload multiple images with resizing in jquery to django backend server

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, image-resizing, image-compression

I am using Jquery file upload and compressing code for images with this i can select multiple images but it only compressing and uploading the last image selected

so how can i upload multiple images with compression? What modifications are needed plzz suggest.

Html code:

```
<input  id="fileupload" type="file" name="file" multiple>
```

Jquery code:

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$(function () {
'use strict';
var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
var url = '/dashboard/{{name}}/{{name_product_type.type_product|urlencode}}/{{abc}}/';

    $('#postbtn').on('click', function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                data = $this.data();
            $this
                .off('click')
                .text('Abort')
                .on('click', function () {
                    $this.remove();
                    data.abort();
                });
            data.submit().always(function () {
                $this.remove();
            });
        });


$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: url,
    crossDomain: false,
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    uploadMultiple: true, // allow multiple upload
    autoProcessQueue: false, // prevent dropzone from uploading automatically
    maxFiles: 5,
    autoUpload: false,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    maxFileSize: 5000000, // 5 MB
    // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
    // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
    // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
    disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
        .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
    previewMaxWidth: 100,
    previewMaxHeight: 100,
    previewCrop: true
}).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#files');
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        var node = $('<p/>')
                .append($('<span/>').text(file.name));
        if (!index) {
            node
                .append('<br>')
               // .append($('#postbtn').clone(true).data(data));
        }
        node.appendTo(data.context);

    });
}).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
    var index = data.index,
        file = data.files[index],
        node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
    if (file.preview) {
        node
            .prepend('<br>')
            .prepend(file.preview);
    }
    if (file.error) {
        node
            .append('<br>')
            .append(file.error);
    }
    if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
        data.context.find($('#postbtn').data(data));
          //  .text('Upload')
           // .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
    }
}).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
        'width',
        progress + '%'
    );
}).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
        var link = $('<a>')
            .attr('target', '_blank')
            .prop('href', file.url);
        $(data.context.children()[index])
            .wrap(link);
    });
}).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
        var error = $('<span/>').text(file.error);
        $(data.context.children()[index])
            .append('<br>')
            .append(error);
    });
}).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
    .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
```

Django backend :
 in views.py :

```
        files=request.FILES.getlist('file')
```

and then save it to database.
Everrthing works fine. Even image is compressed at the output but we intent to have multiple images compressed and save back to database at one hit of button.
Any sugestions are welcomed... 
Thank you...